# Toggle class after timeout with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to build a flyout cart menu that stays open after a page refresh on a button click and form submit.
After a few seconds and after the page refresh the flyout menu needs to be closed automatically. I'm using a jquery cookie and a toggleClass for this.

I'm facing two problems:

1) How to remove the class after x seconds
2) When I click the button twice then the menu goes back to it's normal state which is hidden.

What I have is this:

```
 <li class="cart-top">
   <ul>....</ul>
</li>


$(document).ready(function() {
  var cart_class = $.cookie('cart_class');
  if(cart_class) {
    $('.cart-top').attr('class', cart_class);
  }
});


$(".pp .addToCart").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var $form = $(this).closest('form');
  var qty = $('.qty_input input').val();
  var variant = $('#product_configure_variants').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    url: $form.attr('action')+variant+'/?quantity='+qty,
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(data, status){
      if(status == 'success'){

       // refresh the page
       setTimeout(function(){
          location.reload();
        },200);

        // add class back to the menu
        $(".cart-top").toggleClass("hover");
        $.cookie('cart_class', $('.cart-top').attr('class'));

        // remove the class after 2 seconds
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.cart-top').removeClass('hover');
        },2000);
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

I really can't see what I'm doing wrong except for using `setTimeout` twice. I've read numerous post on this but none is really dealing with some sort of same problem.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The second `setTimeout` won't have any effect. When you reload the page, all the current scripts are stopped. You need to do that in the code at the beginning that runs when the page is loaded.

Comment: @Barmar: Ok thx but that adds class `hover` on any page refresh.

Comment: Put something in the cookie that says what it should do when the page reloads.

Comment: @Barmar: Ok thx again... but if I know how or what I wouldn't have this question ;)